# How to import libraries defined in eclipse.userlibraries into Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've imported eclipse projects in Intellij. The libraries of the project are defined in eclipse.userlibraries.

How can I import these libraries after I've imported the projects. I did got prompted to do so during import, but the list of dependencies was to large, and wasn't able to scroll down and add the path to the `eclipse.userlibraries` file. (I would classify this as a bug in Intellij)

Answer (score 0):

as crazy as it sounds, i rotated my desktop using CTRL + ALT + ARROW, and pasted the path.

Things you have to do when the scrollbar is not there, really :) Maybe it helps someone